# How do I make the actionListener use if/else statement to execute an operation after all the JtextFields and Password have been checked

Tags: java

```
    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String  firstName = firstNameField.getText();\\gets user input
            String  surname =   surnameField.getText();\\gets user input
            String  username    =   usernameField.getText();\\gets user input
            char[] newPassword  =   password.getPassword();
            char[] confirmNew   =   confirmPassword.getPassword();
```

How do I make below conditional statement check if all fields are completed and displays the completion responses.

```
            if(firstName == null && surname ==null && username == null && newPassword == null && confirmNew ==  null){
                completionResponse.setText("All fields must be completed");
            }else
            completionResponse.setText("Congratulations! account have been successfully created");
        }

    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking for. You are showing us the code that fetches information from your other UI elements; and you are showing us the code that checks those results; and you already put that in an if/else statement. So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Use "||" instead of "&&". You obviously want it to fail if any of the fields is empty. "true && false" will be "false" ... And I highly doubt your GUI fields' getText() methods will return null. So you may want to check for "nullOrEmpty".

Comment: On the if else block, only the "else" part executes. The program does not check if the fields are null, so it skips the "if" part.

Comment: **Are** the fields null? Can you verify via a debugger that they are null when the program executes that line? I doubt it. Remember, the block would only be executed if all of the fields are null. I suspect that all of them might be empty (if you tested with no entries made). But what you actually want to check is if **any** of them is empty. So it doesn't "skip the if part" - the condition just does not evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you are checking if all fields == null, which is probably false (assuming at least something is filled in).

```
if(firstName == null || surname ==null || username == null || newPassword == null || confirmNew ==  null){
completionResponse.setText("All fields must be completed");
...
```

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, your assistance helped.